# how to compare numbers in a list

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to code three card poker and i need to know how to compare numbers in a list

i need something like:

```
deck = []
amountInDeck = 1
hearts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
spades = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
clubs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
diamonds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
while amountInDeck <= 52:
  cardSelector = random.randint(1,13)
  #here i need to make sure if there is already for of one kind of number in the deck list then it needs to re pick the number and add it to deck then repeat.
  deck.append(cardSelector)
```

Comment: use for loops and if statements

Comment: also you should use a dict instead of having 4 different lists

Comment: another thing, `while amountInDeck <= 52:` will always loop unless you add `amountInDeck += 1` in that loop

Comment: i know i forgot to copy that

Comment: Have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a function like this:

```
def ifFourIn(deck, val):
    val_count = 0
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        if val == deck[i]:
            val_count+=1
    if (val_count > 4):
        return True
    return False
```

What this function does is that it checks if the value occurs within the list 4 or more times using a `for` loop and `if` statements. The way you would use it within your `while` loop would be like this:

```
while amountInDeck <= 52:
  cardSelector = random.randint(1,13)
  if (ifFourIn(deck,cardSelector)):
      continue
  deck.append(cardSelector)
  amountInDeck += 1
```

Note that I also added `amountInDeck += 1` at the end because it was going to end up in a infinite loop. The code I added essentially uses the function (which returns a `True` or `False`) to check if there's four or more of `val` inside of `deck`. If so, it'll skip the rest of the code and go back to the start of the loop.

Comment: thank you but one error is the line     if (valcount >= 4): has to be     if (valcount > 4):

Comment: Changed it. Thanks for catching that @aozzya1

Comment: Did this fix the problem? @aozzya1

Comment: yeah it fixed it.

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem, you can set it as solved using the green checkmark to let others know this problem has been solved! @aozzya1